# Common causes for memory leaks

Tags: performance, memory-leaks

What are the most common/frequent memory leaks programmers use to run into when developing applications?

Interested in all kind of languages, would be nice if this could evolve into a `community wiki` where to see fixes for common leaks in different languages.

## Update

I have a suggestion to limit this conversation to `C` related languages, .NET and Python. I think these are often used languages, and often beginners try to work with these. In case more languages are needed, edit.

Comment: While there's promise in this question, I think failing to scope it to a particular language or environment will cause it to be defocused and unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDIT** this to add similar points.

**In C++,**

1. Forgetting to delete a pointer object.

**In PHP,**

1. PHP takes cares of memory management. It automatically deletes the memory of a variable when it goes out of scope.
2. On long running PHP scripts, it's a good idea to manually close unneeded socket connections, free result objects, etc.

**In .NET**

1. Failing to unregister event handlers.

Comment: To add to this: on long running PHP scripts, it's a good idea to manually close unneeded socket connections, free result objects, etc.

Answer (score 1):

C++

```
void Foo()
{
    Object* newObject = new Object();
}
```

Object is initialised in new memory but is never deleted hence memory leak.

To clean up the memory for out of scope new'd objects one must use the delete keyword.

```
void Foo()
{
    Object* newObject = new Object();
    delete newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET

Failing to unregister event handlers.